# How to get the failed step of a scenario in cucumber-js?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am trying to create a custom report, so far I have got these values in my failed.json

```
{
    "status": "FAILED",
    "feature": "tc795639 To verify the negative validation check for field \"family_name\" with incorrect data",
    "from": "features/address_post_validation.feature",
    "data": "{\"incorrect_dataValue\":{\"family_name\":\"\"}}",
    "type": "AssertionError",
    "error": "expected false to be true",
    "details": "AssertionError\n    + expected - actual\n\n    -false\n    +true\n\n    at World.<anonymous> (/home/user/Documents/features/step_definitions/stepdefs_common_func.js:27:31)"
  }
```

From: / when consoling scenario in after hook , I get these values. But I am not getting any data
related to failed step

```json
{
  "gherkinDocument": {
    "feature": {
      "tags": [],
      "location": {},
      "language": "en",
      "keyword": "Feature",
      "name": "Check Validations for each fields as per the spec of post /address",
      "description": "",
      "children": []
    },
    "comments": [],
    "uri": "features/address_post_validation.feature"
  },
  "pickle": {
    "id": "32ea89c6-7701-4f97-a2da-8339b35fcee7",
    "uri": "features/address_post_validation.feature",
    "astNodeIds": [],
    "name": "tc795639 To verify the negative validation check for field \"family_name\" with incorrect data",
    "language": "en",
    "steps": [
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object],
      [Object]
],
    "tags": []
  },
  "testCaseStartedId": "3b2118fc-1e87-4524-b5f5-ff905e70559c",
  "result": {
    "duration": { "seconds": 0, "nanos": 2827014 },
    "status": "FAILED",
    "message": "AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected values to be strictly equal:\n\n401 !== 400\n\n    + expected - actual\n\n    -401\n    +400\n\n    at World.<anonymous> (/home/user/Documents/features/step_definitions/stepdefs_common_func.js:133:10)",
    "exception": {
      "type": "AssertionError",
      "message": "Expected values to be strictly equal:\n\n401 !== 400\n"
    }
  },
  "willBeRetried": false
}
```

and this is the scenario.pickle.steps

```
[
  {
    id: '381f9425-50d0-4249-8699-b496d77062db',
    text: 'following is body data:',
    type: 'Context',
    argument: { docString: [Object] },
    astNodeIds: [ '23628ec2-499c-45c9-bf5b-4398e609f0ff' ]
  },
  {
    id: 'ab38523e-890f-4436-9b02-dd2fa506ff7b',
    text: 'user send a "post" request to "my url",
    type: 'Action',
    argument: { docString: [Object] },
    astNodeIds: [
      '04961ebc-4e8c-4cb3-b910-8775569d165f',
      'df2aec66-8d24-4972-9497-eea8bae416cf'
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '82bf8ad4-1c29-4859-b07f-b46fc3bdcd7c',
    text: 'status should be 400',
    type: 'Outcome',
    argument: undefined,
    astNodeIds: [
      '0f5ca771-e523-48f8-b215-9b47f7e67b16',
      'df2aec66-8d24-4972-9497-eea8bae416cf'
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 'a729c9db-aee7-4e91-8683-941b59943202',
    text: 'the response should contain the following keys:',
    type: 'Unknown',
    argument: { docString: [Object] },
    astNodeIds: [
      '3645a605-aa58-40b3-8868-5a965de6b5bd',
      'df2aec66-8d24-4972-9497-eea8bae416cf'
    ]
  }
]
```

note that there are no detailed specified anywhere in this about failed step.
Be we know that step is somehow mapped as failed in cucumber.

Basically I would like to include or retrieve this one line after ✖ that is:

"✖ Then status should be 400 # features/step_definitions/stepdefs_common_func.js:131"

So that I can format it to "Then status should be 400" and add to my failed json.

```
✖ Then status should be 400 # features/step_definitions/stepdefs_common_func.js:131

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected values to be strictly equal:
       
       401 !== 400
       
           + expected - actual
       
           -401
           +400
       
           at World.<anonymous> (/home/user/Documents/features/step_definitions/stepdefs_common_func.js:133:10)
```

I have tried many sources to retrieve this , but unfortunately none of that worked. I even tried gpt , which is showing an snippet like,

```
After(function(scenario) {
  if (scenario.result.status === 'failed') {
    const failedStep = scenario.pickle.steps.find(step => step.result.status === 'failed');
    if (failedStep) {
      console.log('Failed Scenario:', scenario.pickle.name);
      console.log('Failed Step Text:', failedStep.text);
    }
  }
});
```

But the problem with this is that there is no key named "step" anywhere in 'scenario' .
Many thing I tried is similar or same, with "*.step" returning undefined.

So, how can I get the failed scenario step?

Comment: You may need to compile more information about each step from the output of the AfterStep hook, and append the status of each step to the scenario pickle while your suite is running.

The scenario pickle is in reference to the scenario, and doesn't include results for steps in my experience (have built 3 custom reporters over the years)

Comment: Can you please explain that? In brief, my question was the cucumber somehow knows there is a failed step that they output with an "x" mark or "?" into the console log depending on the type of error. Right? So if somehow I can add that to the scenario object at the runtime, I can get it in after hook! That's what I believe.

Comment: Store the gherkin document from the scenario in a Before, you'll also want to add an AfterStep hook, much like the After hook you have in place - match the steps from AfterStep with the steps in the Before - they should share the same ID, and it includes status for the step. Finally add the status for the entire scenario using an After hook. The data needed is in separate places - you'll know whether you'd prefer to store it as an object, or within your world class, or outputting everything to a folder system so you can build the report separately

Comment: **Example output from `step.pickle`:** `{
  id: 'e9610476-4995-4b26-9bd7-01a915225a13',
  text: 'I go to the "login" page',
  type: 'Context',
  argument: undefined,
  astNodeIds: [ 'ffaf837f-c9ae-4b3a-999f-3ee44ff16db0' ]
}`
**Example output from `step.result`:** `{ duration: { seconds: 3, nanos: 170917790 }, status: 'PASSED' }`

Comment: I kinda get the idea. But when I console "scenario.step" it returns an error. Do you have any kind of referencce code , that is working on your side?

Comment: This snippet here is what you need for the steps to append `AfterStep(async function (step){
  console.log(step.pickleStep)
  console.log(step.result)
})`

I think it's time to write a proper answer, all the information is here

Answer (score 0):

Store the gherkin document from the scenario in a Before, preferably to the World object (where a custom traceScenario function would append the step to the right place for you)

```js
Before({name: "Saving Scenario For Steps", timeout: 60 * 1000}, function (scenario) {
    return this.traceScenario(scenario)
})
```

You'll also want to add an AfterStep hook, much like the After hook you have in place

Match the steps from AfterStep with the steps in the Before - they should share the same ID, and it includes status for the step. Finally add the status for the entire scenario using an After hook.

The data needed is in separate places - you'll know whether you'd prefer to store it as an object, or within your world class, or outputting everything to a folder system so you can build the report separately

This snippet here is what you need from the steps to append, and should get the ball rolling:

```js
AfterStep(function (step){   
   console.log(step.pickleStep)   
   console.log(step.result) 
})
```

Example output from step.pickle:

```js
{   
   id: 'e9610476-4995-4b26-9bd7-01a915225a13',   
   text: 'I go to the "login" page',   
   type: 'Context',   
   argument: undefined,   
   astNodeIds: [ 'ffaf837f-c9ae-4b3a-999f-3ee44ff16db0' ] 
}
```

Example output from step.result:

```js
{ 
   duration: { 
      seconds: 3, 
      nanos: 170917790 
    }, 
    status: 'PASSED' 
}
```